# Show Div When Radio Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to use this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  div {display: none}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.radio1').click(function () {
        $('.div1').show();
    });
    $('.radio2').click(function () {
        $('.div2').show();
    });
</script>

<label><input type="radio" name="group1" class="radio1"></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" class="radio2"></label>

<div class="div1">Radio1 selected !</div>
<div class="div2">Radio2 selected !</div>
```

But when I check any radio then notthing happens.

I tried with Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/
and same no results

Any idea?

Comment: On **Frameworks & Extensions** change **No-Library (pure JS)** to **jQuery 1.9.1** and then Run.

Comment: the reason your JSfiddle is not working is because you have not included jQuery

Comment: Do you want the div to hide again when the radio button is unchecked?

Comment: What about local html file. It doesn't work on my computer with Chrome and IE. I have noticed that this file is loading for like 10 seconds then I can see content. Something like this jqurey.min.js file are loaded long time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You have no ID on the `<div>`
2. You have to set the `onchange` event of the `<radio>`

This works without jQuery:

```
<label><input type="radio" onchange="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none'" name="group1" class="radio1"></label>

<label><input type="radio" onchange=" document.getElementById('div2').style.display='block';document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none'" name="group1" class="radio2"></label>

<div id="div1" class="div1 content">Radio1 selected !</div>
<div id ="div2" class="div2 content">Radio2 selected !</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/14/)

Comment: Inline JavaScript is really bad form, and in this case it becomes apparent why if you were to add more radio buttons (the code for 4 buttons would be unbearably ugly)

Comment: Your are welcome and there is your Jquery that presevre some bytes because the basic javascript is supported on all browsers @xec

Comment: @K3rnel31 With a CDN (as OP is using) you are likely saving 0 bytes by not using jQuery. But jQuery or not, you should always separate your concerns, keep the javascript in an external js file instead of inline! This is web development 101 :) - In addition, your update with the function named `$()` is not making the script more scalable at all, try to make a demo with 4 buttons...

Comment: Bad form and has almost nothing to do with the actual question

Comment: hah is abnormal vote down with correct answer ! are you jealous or what?@antishok

Comment: @K3rnel31 "the user want to use javascript and not Jquery" What makes you say this? The question both contains jQuery code and is (correctly) tagged jQuery... You are reading the feedback we provide, but it doesn't seem to sink in. This answer contains bad practices and the only reason it was accepted is because OP is new enough not to be able to distinguish this. Did you try making a demo with four radio buttons yet?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your function with DOM ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('.radio1').click(function () {
        $('.div1').show();
    });
    $('.radio2').click(function () {
        $('.div2').show();
    });
});
```

Yourfiddle was not including jQuery...
Had you checked the console you would have seen this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Fixed [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/3/)

Answer (score 1):

**Or** you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/y8f2p/

Now the version below is bit generic approach uses the numeric value from the radio class. `:)`

rest see above gdoron has mentioned few other things!

**Code**

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {

    $('.div' + $(this).prop('class').match(/\d+/)).toggle(); // OR .show whatever fits your need
});
```

Comment: If he only wants to show the div associated with the radio button, this is probably closer to what he wants: http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/11/

Comment: @gdoron Bruvooo awesome to see you! `B-)`

Comment: @xec saweet man! Chuck your fiddle as post below, I will upvote you `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit Cheers, :) Is the atmosphere in here always this awesome on sundays? I should come here more often!

Comment: @xec you roll with awesome peeps and you will be happy chappy bruvoo! everyone around are pretty saweet! `:)` good reply below! good man! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

The other replies by @Tats_innit, @Dan and @gdoron are absolutely correct:

- you need to select "jQuery" in the frameworks dropdown in jsFiddle to get it included
- wrap your code in [dom ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) because you've put it before the html elements you're trying to select (if you include your scripts at the end of the document you're golden!)
- if you want each radio button associated with a specific div you can do it with a single click handler:

@Tats_innit did a fancy regex match to get the radio button number, which can work well, but I opted for more explicit markup, using a html-* attribute. Also, I **assume you only want to show one div at a time**, hence the use of radio controls?

#### HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" class="radio1" data-divclass="div1"></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" class="radio2" data-divclass="div2"></label>

<div class="div1 content">Radio1 selected !</div>
<div class="div2 content">Radio2 selected !</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // select radio buttons by name
    $('[type="radio"][name="group1"]').click(function () {
        // hide all the content divs
        $('.content').hide();
        // then show the div matching the class from the html
        $('.' + $(this).data("divclass")).show(); 
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/11/

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work on my local html file. Thank you anyway. I really appreciate your help guys !

Comment: @maniootek You can see from the demo that clearly, this works. If you can't get it working locally, try including jQuery locally as well (download the file etc). I urge you not to opt for K3rnel31's solution as coding in that manner is guaranteed to give you headaches later on.

Comment: when I download "jquery.min.js" file and load with my html file then it works now! Why it doesn't work when I try to use that line: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I just found out. There is "http:" missing in script src. Now it is working locally !

Comment: @maniootek The URL syntax starting with `//` means it's trying to use the same scheme (https/http) as the site it's hosted on. Locally this might translate to `file://` and not work when that file doesn't exist locally. On a live site or a local webserver (`http://localhost/`) it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It suggest the usage of data-target attribute

```
$( "input[type=radio]" ).on( "click", function() {
    var x = $(this).attr("data-target")
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {   
        $(x).addClass("visible")
    }
});
```

Add data-target attributes on the radio element itself. e.g data-target=".div1"
will add a class called "visible" to a div with class ".div1"

Dont forget to add that class :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Ac9c4/15/

Comment: What is the `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` for? If a radio button is clicked, it will be checked as a consequence, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
   $('.radio1').click(function () {
       $('.div1').show();
       $('.div2').hide();
   });
   $('.radio2').click(function () {
       $('.div2').show();
       $('.div1').hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to the jsfiddle libraries